# How to set exact width of columns in react-table version 8 which will not change in any condition

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v8, tanstack

I'm using a table with an expand option while working on a react table. With react table version 7, which I used to make this table, I was able to adjust the width of each table column using the width property and the useBlockLayout hook. Now I'm switching to react-table version 8, or tan table, for performance reasons.

In version 8, I can create a table with the expand option and also set the width using the size option, but whatever size I enter is not applied exactly to columns. For example, if I enter 118 as size, it takes 120 or 110 in pixels. Additionally, if I click the expand all button and the size of the first column changes, it reduces the size of other columns.

Any width I specify in the older version appears to be applied to the table, and columns' sizes are preserved if the size of an outer contained window changes.

In conclusion, I want to give the table fixed column sizes that shouldn't alter under any circumstances.

1. My implementation of react table version 7 with expand option and  fixed columns width.
   [React table in version 7 with fixed column width](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-nightingale-f1f0jz?file=/src/App.js)
2. My implementation of react table version 8 with expand option and variable columns width
   [Link to my implementation](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vigorous-sanderson-zlklzz?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A3%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A209%2C%22startColumn%22%3A3%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A209%7D%5D)

In First implementation I have set width and that exact width is applied in version 7.

But in version 8 of table given size is not applied to column table. And my constraint is I don't want to increase the width and height of table Container Class which is holding this table

Please refer both the implementation of mine and please tell me what is I am missing in tan table implementation because of that it is not maintaining the width of column